# How to populate a cell in a datagridview with co-ordinates

Tags: vb.net

I need to know how to populate a single cell within a datagridview in Visual Basic with just a row and column co-ordinate. So for example I have row co-ordinate: 10 and column co-ordinate: 10 and within that cell I want to Write Hello, How would I do that?

Comment: Got any code you can post? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing this, thats why I'm asking. I've tried                 DGV1.SelectedCells().RowIndex(RowCoOrdinate)
                DGV1.SelectedCells().ColumnIndex(ColumnCoOrdinate) however this didn't work.

Comment: I've also tried DGV1.SelectedCells(RowCoOrdinate, ColumnCoOrdinate).Value = "Hello" however that didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below, it will help you..

```
//It sets the value "Hello" to 10th Rows 10th Cell

DataGridView1.Rows(10).Cells(10).Value = "Hello"
```